# Différence entre un groupe pronominal et un groupe nominal

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

Dans la phrase suivante,

> *Tous trois* prirent la direction de la ville voisine.

*tous trois* est-il un groupe pronominal??

Answer (score 1):

*Tous trois* n'as de sens que par référence à un antécédent. Seul le contexte permet de savoir quel est le véritable sujet de cette phrase. Sans lui il est impossible de savoir s'il s'agit de trois personnes ou de trois objets (peut-être des carrosses ?).

*Tous trois* est donc ici utilisé comme un pronom. Et pour cette raison, il peut être appelé « groupe pronominal ». C'est un groupe qui constitue, ou qui est formé autour d'un pronom.